# Azure WebJob using a Cron Expression is not executing

Tags: azure, cron, azure-webjobs

I have read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs#CreateScheduledCRON).

> The CRON expression is composed of 6 fields: {second} {minute} {hour}
>   {day} {month} {day of the week}.

Cron expressions such as `0/15 * * * * *` work. This indicates that the job should run every 15 seconds.

Additionally, a cron expression such as  works.

Now, I want to have my job run at, for example,  22:25... every day.
I tried: `0 25 22 * * *` as well as `* 25 22 * * *`, but neither of them work, both showing `n/a` under the `SCHEDULE`.

Even `0 0 11 * * *` fails to execute.

The only cron expression I have made work is `0/15 * * * * *`.

Why do my cron expressions not work and how can I fix them to run ever day at 22:25?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do my cron expressions not work and how can I fix them to run ever day at 22:25?

I just test following format CRON and it works good on my side.

```
0 25 22 * * *
```

You could create a scheduled WebJob by creating a file named settings.job under the root folder of your WebJob or by setting the CRON in Azure portal when creating a WebJob.

[image]

If your WebJob didn't executed at 22:25. It maybe caused by the timezone on Azure WebJob is UTC±00:00. You could modify your scheduled time to meet your requirement.

Comment: Thank you, it was indeed the timezone issue. My Resource group is in West Europe, so I expected the WebJob TZ to be the same... clearly it isn't, for whatever reason.